# mod_rewrite for clean urls gives 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some troubles with mod_rewrite.

On my index page (index.php) I show a blog and a single blog post page looks like this:
http://www.mydomain.com/blog/post-title

mod_rewrite for this is:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?postslug=$1 [L]
```

This works like a charm.

But I also have another page called artists.php and the url should look like this:
http://www.mydomain.com/artists/artist-name

mod_rewrite for this is:

```
RewriteRule ^artists/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ artists.php?artistslug=$1 [L]
```

This gives me a 500 internal server error and I have no clue why this happens...

Both index.php and artists.php are in the root of my website

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^blog/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?postslug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^artists/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ artists.php?artistslug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Check your apache logs. Is there a chance that artists.php is causing it instead of the mod_rewrite?

Comment: checked it and I get this message:  mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this rule instead of your one with the two `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

I’ve tested it myself and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` seems to contain the wrong value but `-f` is evaluated to *true* anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on:

```
RewriteLog /path/to/file.log
RewriteLogLevel 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([-A-z0-9]+)$ index.php?postslug=$1
RewriteRule ^artists/([-A-z0-9]+)$ artists.php?artistslug=$1
```

Answer (score -1):

The RewriteRule itself looks fine to me, check if the server error occurs if you access the artists.php file directly, without the URL rewriting taking place.

Comment: I checked it and it works fine. Both artists.php and artists.php?artistslug=test work like they should