# .htaccess rewrite with REST style URL 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rest

I'm trying to implement a REST-style URL with a mod-rewrite turned on in .htaccess.  There's a bit of a kicker which is that I'm developing in a test environment (new cpanel account). Here's the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

#REMOVE THIS LINE ON SITE LAUNCH!
RewriteBase /~myNewAccount/

#Hide .php extensions for cleaner URLS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Options All -Indexes
```

The URL I CAN use looks like this:

```
www.example.com/~myNewAccount/index.php/id/50
```

I can access the PATH_INFO here, but when I try to do this:

```
www.example.com/~myNewAccount/index/id/50
```

...I get a 500 internal server error.  I've tried implementing the [solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219135/modrewrite-for-clean-urls-gives-500-internal-server-error) by Gumbo but that mucks things up.

Ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index(/.*)?$ index.php$1 [L]
```

Or if you don’t want *index* to be in the URL path at all:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Problem is i'll have LOTS of base urls (similar to index.php but with other names) and I'd prefer not to actually have a rule in there for every page.  Is this possible?

Comment: @jeerose: If you’re using relative paths in your substitution, then they will always depend on the base path.